# How to open and add SQLite connection to browser with PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, sqlite, pyqt5

I have a code to open the layers of a SQLite database. When executing this code, the layers are loaded correctly (1 & 2). However i also need to connect to the database and show the connection in the browser toolbar.

How doe load the connection and let it show in the database browser (3)?

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setDatabase(r'C:\\path_to_db\\andorra.sqlite')
schema = ''
tables = ['points', 'lines', 'multilinestrings', 'multipolygons', 'other_relations']
display_names = ['points', 'lines', 'multilinestrings', 'multipolygons', 'other relations']
geom_column = 'geometry'

for i in range(len(tables)):
     uri.setDataSource(schema, tables[i], geom_column)
     iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_names[i], 'spatialite')
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found an answer:

```
con = ['name_of_db','C:\\path_to_db\\andorra.sqlite']
QSettings().setValue("SpatiaLite/connections/%s/sqlitepath" %(con[0]), con[1])
iface.reloadConnections()
```

This code will create an 'visible' connection with the given sqlite database.

Complete code:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\\path_to_db\\andorra.sqlite')
    uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
    uri.setDatabase(r'C:\\\\path_to_db\\andorra.sqlite')
    schema = ''
    tables = ['points', 'lines', 'multilinestrings', 'multipolygons', 'other_relations']
    display_names = ['points', 'lines', 'multilinestrings', 'multipolygons', 'other relations']
    geom_column = 'geometry'

    for i in range(len(tables)):
        uri.setDataSource(schema, tables[i], geom_column)
        iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_names[i], 'spatialite')

    db = ['andorra','\\path_to_db\\andorra.sqlite']
    QSettings().setValue("SpatiaLite/connections/%s/sqlitepath" %(db[0]), db[1])
    iface.reloadConnections()

    set_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857)
    QgsProject.instance().setCrs(set_crs)  #setting the osm CRS
```

Comment: Hi I'm currently trying to do the same thing for a geopackage. Any idea how I should adapt this line:  `QSettings().setValue("SpatiaLite/connections/%s/sqlitepath" %(con[0]), con[1])` - i've already tried `QSettings().setValue("GeoPackage/connections/%s/geopackagepath" %(con[0]), con[1])` but that doesn't seem to do it...

Answer (score 0):

For GeoPackage, try:

```
QSettings().setValue("providers/ogr/GPKG/connections/%s/path" %(con[0]),con[1])
```