# PostgreSQL connection doesn't show up in Data Source Manager

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, postgresql

I have data for a PostgreSQL connection. After writing the data in QgsSettings.
The connection works but in the Data Source Manager under PostgreSQL connections is nothing documented. After I restart QGIS, the Data Source Manager shows me my connection.

```
qs = QgsSettings()
qs.beginGroup('/PostgreSQL/connections')
geo_data = "/"+ database_name

qs.setValue(geo_data +"/sslmode","SslDisable")
qs.setValue(geo_data +'/savePassword',"true")
qs.setValue(geo_data +'/saveUsername',"true")
qs.setValue(geo_data + '/username',"user")
qs.setValue(geo_data + '/password',"Password")
qs.setValue(geo_data + '/host',"Data Source")
qs.setValue(geo_data + '/database',"database")
qs.setValue(geo_data + '/port',"5432")

qs.sync()
```

I thought that the settings getting saved automatically and for safety, I also used the sync() function. Maybe someone has an idea of what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to reload your connections instead of `qs.sync()`:

```
iface.reloadConnections()
```

Based on this [How to open and add SQLite connection to browser with PyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307325/how-to-open-and-add-sqlite-connection-to-browser-with-pyqgis)

Comment: it works for MSSQL and PostgreSQL but not for Oracle